# Flutter remove const from Constructor Error. Even if no const is used

Tags: android, flutter, dart

**In the following code, only the Container() constructtor causes the error **

```
    class RideDetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {
      const RideDetailsPage({super.key, required this.rideId});
      final int? rideId;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Ride Details")),
          body: const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Card(
            elevation: 100,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    //LOCATIONS
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          " PAINAVUU\n,IDUKKI,KOAIISAJS ",
                          maxLines: 2,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, size: 50),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          " PAINAVUU\n,IDUKKI,KOAIISAJS ",
                          maxLines: 2,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),                       //               <--ISSUE HERE
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    child: Text("TIME"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )),
      ),
    );
      }
    }
```

It says remove const keyword but there is no const keyword
Note that no other Constructor such as SizedBox() doesn't cause an error.But COntainer()
constructor cause the problem.

Comment: "Note that no other Constructor such as SizedBox() doesn't cause an error.But COntainer() constructor cause the problem." - because `Container` does not have `const` constructor, compare [Container](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container/Container.html) with [SizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox/SizedBox.html)

Comment: You have given const at the start of body `const Padding` so that const is giving you an error as all other child widgets are const but `container` is not so you can't give const to the parent widget. So just remove const from the top and the error will be gone, You need to give `const` to other const widgets separately.